# Select sum from multiple tables into one row

Tags: postgresql

I'm fetching data from a view that I later process through an ETL and eventually push to a database.

Here's an insight on the columns of that view:

```
date      |contractid|netamount|grossamount|ordertype|paymenttype|
----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+
2020-08-01|   1179444|     5883|       6824|RECURRING|BILL       |
2020-08-01|   1179444|      216|        250|FEE      |BILL       |
2020-08-01|   1179445|      444|        500|RECURRING|BILL       |
2020-08-01|   1179445|      111|        222|FEE      |BILL       |
```

My goal is to count those contracts and see the amount of revenue earned per contract. The catch is that a contract can have additional revenues generated by fees, as in the example above.

The issue I am facing is that if I count the contracts + the fees, then the total number of contracts is wrong since it would also count the fees as unique contract.

Additionally, all the costs that belong to a same contract have the same contractId.

My question is:
How do I select a single row per contractId but with the sum of the fees included? That way, I would have the aggregated sum under one contract only.

The result would be something like:

```
date      |contractid|netamount|grossamount|ordertype|paymenttype|
----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+
2020-08-01|   1179444|     6099|       7074|RECURRING|BILL       |
2020-08-01|   1179445|      555|        722|RECURRING|BILL       |
```

What I first tried was to use common table expressions to first select all contracts of type 'RECURRING'. Then in another CTE select all contracts of type 'FEE', and eventually union it or join it all via contractId from the first CTE with the contractId from the second CTE.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to achieve what I was looking for. Any hint/help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with a simple group by `select contractid, sum (netamout), sum(grossamount) group by contractid` ?

Comment: I tried, but Postgres says my other columns need to be in the group by clause as well, which leads to two rows again. Probably because it's a view and not a table?

Answer (score 1):

```
select ov.date, ov.contactid, ov2.netamount, ov2.grossamount, 
ov.ordertype, ov.paymenttype 
from original_view ov
left outer join (select sum(netamount) netamount, 
sum(grossamount) grossamount, contactId
  from original_view group by contactid) ov2  on ov.contactid = ov2.contactid
where ordertype = 'RECURRING'
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. Can you explain what you exactly do here?

Comment: This query does an outer join on a temp table. If you are not familiar with join's you should read up on them and practice using them.   So the sum is done outside the original query.   To see what is happening you can run the select that is used in the join outside the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a count of distinct and them sum totals like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contractid) as contracts, 
       SUM(netamount) as net,
       SUM(grossamount) as gross
FROM table_name
```

Comment: The issue is that Postgres forces me to use gross/net and the rest of my select parameters in the group by... column "grossamount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. As soon as I do it, I have no distinct id anymore